Can I replace this resistor (in USB adapter that plugs to mains) with this other resistor?
I would just test this instead of asking here, but because this goes to mains, dangerous voltages and all that, I prefer to be safe than sorry.
An old USB adapter stopped working, and I finally took it apart to find this:

I used a lookup table online, and find that it should be 10 ohm 0.02% --brown black black gold yellow (unless I'm reading it wrong and it should be 430 ohm 1% -- yellow orange black black brown).

So I reached into my pile of recovered components and found this guy (brown black black gold):

But while reading up, some sources said this might also be an inductor (!)
As you can tell, I'm still learning, so any further info you might give will be greatly appreciated.

The safest way is to throw the entire device into garbage bin.

I'll add one thing about safety. Whatever this circuit board is, it came out of some enclosure. That enclosure is a crucial part of the safety. I can't tell what the main bit of this looks like, but most mains-to-USB adapters are two prong which generally means they need double insulation (two or more layers of insulation). Unless you took that circuit board out of an enclosure that had screws and no glue or mechanical retention etc you probably can't get the whole unit back together perfectly. If you don't get it back together perfectly there's a few possible safety concerns:

(*) The insulation isn't complete allowing an area where an air-gap (instead of insulation) can allow conduction by ionizing the air. (*) The entire enclosure becomes loose and falls off, then you have exposed conductors. (*) Variations on the above, like pushing in USB and something moving around.

My general rule is to not try to fix anything that goes to mains and is designed to go inside a plastic enclosure type thing because chances are low that I can do a sufficiently good job of it for it to be safe. Just for contrast, what I myself and willing to work on (and am in no way suggesting anyone else should follow me) is power electronics inside metal enclosures where I can open the enclosure with screws and don't have to deform, break or pull apart anything to access the circuitry.


Can I replace this resistor (in USB adapter that plugs to mains) with this other resistor?

No, for 2 reasons:

That resistor has got hot and failed open for a reason - probably a failed component elsewhere. Unless you find & fix the original fault, replacing the resistor will not result in a working mains adapter.

And, perhaps more importantly:

The original resistor is a special fusible resistor. See its refdes on the PCB: FR1 (Fusible Resistor 1). It has done its job by failing open-circuit under overload, without catching fire. Fusible resistors often have unusual body colours e.g. green, although there is no universal standard for that (see the linked Q&A below). The resistor you are considering to replace it, looks like a standard resistor and seems larger e.g. a higher-wattage.
So when it is overloaded (as may happen unless you fix the original fault - see point 1 above) the replacement standard resistor will likely overheat and not fail in a controlled manner, like the original fusible resistor did. Using that could result in fire, personal injury etc. Fusible resistors are typically marked on schematics as safety items, only to be replaced with exact equivalents.
Therefore the resistor you show from your component pile, is not a suitable replacement.



it should be 10 ohm 0.02% --brown black black gold yellow

It isn't a 0.02% tolerance resistor in that location in the circuit (it will be in series with the incoming mains supply). That yellow (?) band has been used by the resistor's manufacturer (whoever that is) to indicate something manufacturer-specific; in this case, probably that it's a fusible resistor.
More info about fusible resistor markings in this previous topic:
Color Code for Fusible or Flame Retardant Resistors: Data Sheets, Standards?

It's good that you asked the question. However any attempt to repair mains-powered devices has risks, especially for the novice or less-experienced engineer. To slightly adapt the comment by Ale..chenski, the safest (and most environmentally-friendly) thing to do, is to put it in for electrical recycling, instead of trying to repair it.

Thank you so much! I not only got an answer to the question but learned a lot from your answer. Thank you again! (I will no longer attempt to fix this adapter. I found a bit of solder bridging two traces past a capacitor, I figure that could have been the cause, but no way to know, since that could've been the result of the blowing of the FR as well.)

Could the #1 be triggered by overloading the charger on the output side meaning there is nothing bad with the charger, except for the blown fuse?

@Crowley Almost certainly not. One, chargers are supposed to have internal protections against overload or overtemperature and fold back or shut off the output. Two, primary side protection is usually rated for a much higher current than could be expected in normal operation. The 10 ohm ~1W resistor would probably be OK for 300mA continuous in service, or about 30W out at 120V in - more if on a 230V supply.

@Crowley More likely is an internal fault (possibly the solder bridge OP has found). The other very common cause is overvoltage: the MOV begins conducting significant current, the MOV may or may not fail to short, then the resistor/fuse blows to clear the fault.

@insaner - You're very welcome,. Re: "I found a bit of solder bridging two traces past a capacitor, I figure that could have been the cause, but no way to know {...}". It would need reverse-engineering of the circuit including the SMD components on the other side of the PCB, to see if that hypothesis fits with the events. Also, if there is an incorrect solder bridge, we would have to consider why this adapter didn't fail immediately. FYI I've seen initially worrying solder bridges on mass-produced items which I later found didn't cause a functional problem, as there was a PCB trace {...}

{...} joining the same two points anyway. So a solder bridge is not always a problem. || One note of caution: Please don't buy cheap mains adapters from Amazon, eBay or similar marketplace-type sites. I have dismantled several which had been bought by friends & family, and seen some truly scary design & construction inside many of them. The YouTube channel "Diode Gone Wild" has done teardowns of USB mains adapters which you might find interesting (here is a search result page on YouTube of some relevant videos).

The usual pathway of blowing the serial FR of an SMPS is not a failure in the SMPS itself, but arcing in the mains socket (or upstream) instead. This is why replacing the resistor only COULD be a viable repair strategy. Of course, knowing what you are doing is highly advisable.
